# Como usar Google Analytics com ionic 3

Tags: php, mysql, typescript, ionic3, google-analytics-api

Boa tarde, 
 Estou fazendo um app usando o ionic 3 e uso a API RESTful com php para conexão com o banco de dados Mysql, e preciso usar o Google Analytics no projeto, porem não consigo achar um tutorial funcional, se alguem puder me mandar algum link, eu ficaria muito grato.

Comment: Uma opção é usar o Google Analytics para Firebase, que uma solução para aplicativos. [https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/?hl=pt-br](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/?hl=pt-br)

Comment: Você sabe se é possível utilizar o firebase e mysql ao mesmo tempo, onde o firebase vai ser so usado pra coleta de dados pro analytics.

Comment: Você pode usar só o produto Analytics do Firebase. Você pode usar o plugin [cordova-plugin-firebase-analytics](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/firebase-analytics/).

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda